# changing the position of a caption

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

I have a code for putting a figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{some_narrow_and_tall_image.pdf}
\caption{caption of the figure which can be pretty long}
\end{figure}
```

The page format is single-column. Right now the caption appears below the image, as expected from this code. I would like to set it up so that the caption is on the right hand-side of the image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [floatrow package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capbesideposition=right]{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\fcapside
  {\caption{A nice figure.}} 
  {\rule{4cm}{4cm}} %Replace with image
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution with [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
        \rule{8cm}{4cm} %Replace with image
    \end{minipage}  
    \begin{minipage}[]{.15\textwidth}
        \rotcaption{A nice figure.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here, the placement on the side itself is solved using `minipage` environments. The advantage over the answer by Ian Thompson is that the caption is rotated, which I think is better if it's long.

See resulting output below:

[image]